# Python Scraping Problem with Beautifulsoup on Zara

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, find

I'm trying to webscrape Zara with this code(below), in the result I want to get the price of the product but I cant and I get the answer "[ ]". What should I do ?
Thanks in advance.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

HEADERS = ({
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) `your text`Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept-Language": "tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"})

url6 = "https://www.zara.com/tr/tr/erkek-blazerlar-l608.html?v1=2298109"
webpage6 = requests.get(url6, HEADERS)
soup6 = BeautifulSoup(webpage6.content, "html.parser")

r = str(soup6.find_all("span", {"class":"product-grid-seo-info__header"}))
print(r)
```

run--> result : []

Try to scrape price of the product

Answer (score 1):

There `<meta>` refresh you need to follow to get the final page:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/117.0"
}

url = "https://www.zara.com/tr/tr/erkek-blazerlar-l608.html?v1=2298109"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

url2 = "https://www.zara.com" + (
    soup.select_one('meta[http-equiv="refresh"]')["content"]
    .split("=", maxsplit=1)[-1]
    .strip("'")
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url2, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

price = soup.select_one(".price__amount").text
print(f"{price=}")
```

Prints:

```
price='1.999,00 TL'
```